# Calling databricks notebook using Databricks Job api runs-submit endpoint using AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, parameter-passing, databricks

I am trying to establish an AWS lambda function which calls a databricks notebook (in the event of an s3 trigger).How can I make it possible this by using python coding in Lambda function also need to pass parameter from the files in s3 bucket to databricks notebook. Kindly help

Comment: I think this one can help you https://databricks.com/blog/2016/10/11/using-aws-lambda-with-databricks-for-etl-automation-and-ml-model-serving.html

Comment: @Vikas Damodar   Hi Vikas,  there code written in Node.js. Is it possible to connect to Databricks and execute notebook using python code by passing parameters?

Comment: Please also post what your idea of the solution is, and what you've done so far to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Databricks Jobs API to [run an existing job](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#run-now) with new parameters or [submit an adhoc run](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-submit).

The [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/#) library is a popular one for making REST calls using Python.